# databricks Metastore is down

Tags: databricks, hive-metastore, databricks-unity-catalog

When I want to run notebook in Databricks, all queries, saves and reads take really long and I found error message in the clusters event log that says:

> Metastore is down

[image]

So, I think cluster is not able to connect to the metastore at the moment. I tried to create another cluster but with the same result. Unity catalog`s Metastore is on ADLS gen2 and we use premium workspace.
After few minutes command will finish. But simple load of delta table with few records takes 5 minutes or so.

Here example. Two rows in dataframe took 5 minutes to save.
[image]

Here is catalog config:
[image]

We use this cluster config.
[image]

Dont know for now what is the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Im not sure if message "metastore is down" is related to Hive legacy metastore or new Unity catalog metastore. I  can see that message everytime I start up the cluster exactly 6 minutes after the start.